# Codeigniter - Pass array from controller, to view, and then to another controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, controller

I have a controller which handles the adding of records to a database. Sometimes these records require a couple of passwords to be entered, to "sign the record". Therefore, when the form is submitted, it is passed to a function in the controller called "getSignatures." This will load a view with inputs for the passwords needed. The users will then enter their passwords to "sign the document". This will then be passed to a function in the controller called "checkSignatures," which will call a function in the model to check the passwords.

However, I still need to pass through or save all the data from when the form is submitted.

I have tried using a global variable to save the form data, but when the checkSignatures function is called, it's called through a new controller. I also tried passing through the form data to the view, saving it in a hidden input and then passing it back through post but you can't save an array in a hidden input.

Any ideas would be great, and sorry for the long-winded question.

Comment: Why don't you use AJAX to check for those signatures and do the actual post once all data is validated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using sessions as  described [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html). In particular you should look at CodeIgniter's flashdata.

Sessions will be stored on the server for the entirety of the user's browsing session. This will let you access the data again. Flashdata is deleted after the next page load so they don't stick around for long.

Comment: Is it viable to save an array in session/ flashdata? It was my understanding that they were used for more simple variables? In this context it's perfect, since it's only a small array, but for future reference. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if CodeIgniter does it automatically or not, but you can use PHP's serialize(). http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: Ah I used serialize for storing an array in a database so yes, that would work to.